# How to reopen my "on hold" question?

Tags: discussion, support, specific-question, question-quality

If my question still unclear then how to next? (I have deplete my ideas, I need help or more clue as similar comments already in my question, thanks you).

- How to reopen my "on hold" question?
- If my question enough clear then how to reopen it?

My question:

[How to use directly play sound bypass pulseaudio daemon?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/371296/how-allow-special-sound-is-audible-for-all-user-with-pulseaudio)

Answer (score 5):

When you edit your closed question, it's automatically put into a list for other users to review and possibly vote to reopen. This has already happened twice with your question (you [edited](https://unix.stackexchange.com/revisions/371296/6), it was [reviewed](https://unix.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/197310) and left closed, you [edited](https://unix.stackexchange.com/revisions/371296/8) again, and it was [reviewed](https://unix.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/197323) and left closed again).

At the moment I agree with the reviewers; it's still not clear what you're trying to do. If user A is currently logged in and a process owned by user B starts making noise, you still want it to come out of the speakers?

Comment: "special" mean some specific sound  isn't "noise" by we agreed . in fact I nearly solved this question by use `beep` command but `beep` volume too little.

Comment: @illiterate Sorry, we've got a significant language barrier. So you want the ability to make one specific sound effect when something happens on another user's session that's heard by whichever user is currently logged in?

Comment: Yes. If I understand your words correctly then there is any suggest for my question?thank you.

Comment: @illiterate I rewrote your question and reopened it; hopefully I explained what you're looking for correctly